# Git Keeps Prompting For Key To Certain File - Multiple Git Users

Tags: git, github, ssh, multiple-users

I am trying to clone a private github repo, I downloaded github CLI and logged in with my personal account, then I tried to log in with a second account and clone the repo (the repo belongs to the second account). I thought github CLI might make things easier and eliminate the need for configuring. It didn't, it created a ssh key file with a fairly random name for the first account, and no matter what I do (even after creating an ssh key, adding the ssh key with `ssh-add`, modifying `~/.ssh/configure` for multiple users and setting the username and email with the `git config --global user.*` command), it keeps prompting me for the passphrase for the private key associated with my first personal account. This seems like there is a configuration problem somewhere, I tried uninstalling github CLI and it didnt help. *How do I get it to prompt me for the passphrase for the correct user private key file so I can clone my private repo?*

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you didn't give your key to GitHub. First go to `~/.ssh` and look for a file called `id_[something].pub`
Normally the file would be called `id_rsa.pub` or `id_ed25519.pub`. 
(Note that you need to look for the file that has the extension `.pub` and not the similarly named file with NO file extension. ) 
Next, copy the contents of your `.pub` file to your clipboard (Yes, the whole thing). Then, in your browser go to [your github key settings](https://github.com/settings/keys) and click the green button that says "New SSH key". \
You'll see two input boxes, one for the actual key (the big text box at the bottom), and one for the key's name (the one at the top). 
In the bigger input box, paste your `.pub` file's contents, and in the smaller one for the top, just type a name for the key you're adding (For example, mine is "Main Machine"). 
After this, change your repository's protocol to SSH by running the following command in your terminal:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:[username]/[repo name].git
```

This should get SSH working on your system, thus eliminating your error.

Comment: I did try several times to clone the repository using the http, ssh, and git cli protocols. It didnt work, I just tried your suggestion but it didnt work either :(